# Putting 5 A's and 7B's in 4 labelled boxes

Tags: combinatorics

5A's and 7 B's are to be put into 4 labelled boxes so that each box has at least one character. In how many ways can this be done ?

I can solve the problem without restrictions, but how to meet the stipulation ?

Comment: Do you mean each box has both an "A" and a "B"?

Comment: Try finding the numbers of positive solutions of these 2 equations: $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=5$ and $y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}+y_{4}=7$ then multiplying them together.

Comment: drawar, it's not good as having x1=0 but y1=1 seems ok to me?

Comment: No, at least an "A" or "B" in each box.

Comment: David Mitra, together with the "exclusion, inclusion" principle I think.

Comment: Why using the inclusion-exclusion principle here? @Guest86

Comment: @drawar, I've posted what I think the solution is as an anwser

Comment: @Guest86 Ah, yes; you're right. Somehow, I incorrectly thought the "balls" were indistinct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total amount of arrangements is (Using the [Stars and Bars Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29))

$$S_0 = {{5+4-1}\choose{5}}{{7+4-1}\choose{7}}$$

The amount of arrangements with $k$ specific boxes empty is (others may be empty too)

$$S_k = {{5+(4-k)-1}\choose{5}}{{7+(4-k)-1}\choose{7}}$$

and there are $4 \choose k$ ways to pick such specific boxes.

We want the amount of arrangements, not counting the empty boxes, that is $S_0-4S_1$ but $S_1$ picks a certain box being empty - We may count the cases where box 1 is empty and then box 2 is empty but both include cases where both were empty! Using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),

$$\sum_{k=0}^4 (-1)^k {4\choose k}S_k$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand the approach, but the final formula needs some adjustment.

Comment: You're right I wasn't careful enough, fixed.